# Einstein equations in 2 dimensional dilaton-gravity theories

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

In Ref. as [Jensen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06098.pdf), the model Eq.(12) does not contain any kinetic term for the field $\varphi$:

\begin{equation}
S = \int d^2 x \sqrt{-g} \left( \varphi R + U[\varphi] \right)
\end{equation}

The equations of motion (13) follow from stationarity of the action wrt the the metric and $\varphi$.
In particular the former line are the Einstein equations:

\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu} = - D_\mu D_\nu \varphi + g_{\mu\nu}\Box \varphi -\frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{2} U
\end{equation}

Why are there $\varphi$-derivatives terms if no kinetic term exists in the action?

Answer (score 3):

The derivatives come from the $φR$ coupling when you vary with respect to $g^{μν}$. You have to write $R = g^{μν}R_{μν}$ and make use of $g^{μν}δR_{μν} = g_{μν}\Box δg^{μν} - \nabla_{μ}\nabla_{ν}δg^{μν}$, perform integration by parts (twice because you have two derivatives) to make the derivatives act on $φ$ and cancel total divergent terms(boundary terms).

Comment: Do you have a source for the second identity, which includes the covariant derivatives?

Comment: I do not. It is doable once you make use of the fact that the variation of the Christoffel symbol is a tensor and hence you can pick a coordinate system where the Christoffel symbols vanish, since for a tensor any coordinate system is as good as any other.